# What's the best hand against 9 people in the hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em, equity

Imagine the situation you can choose any 2 cards against 9 other players with random cards, is AA mathematically going to have the most equity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on simulations, no other hand besides AA will have higher equity vs. 9 players. The same goes for n number of players 2-8. The hand evaluator I used computes 27% "strength" for pocket aces vs. 9 players pre-flop. The next best hand, KK comes in at 23%.

This is why it is in your best interest to isolate players and raise out some other players with AA and improve your equity in the hand. That said, zero callers pre-flop is no good because you limit the amount of money you can make to what is currently in the pot.

[image]

Comment: The answer is correct but the conclusion to isolate with AA i think is wrong. It may be harder to play against multiple opponents, but if you can get multiple opponents to commit their money against AA, it will be most +EV. Just imagine 27% equity in a $900  pot vs 84% equity in a $200 pot.

Comment: Interesting point. In general, I'd rather iso players with AA than have 8-9 callers every hand. If you go to the flop with 8 other players every time you have AA then the odds of someone making a hand that dominates yours is pretty high. I'd rather they didn't see the flop in the first place. I agree with the EV sentiment. With 1 caller I have the EV of a $100 bet at $152. With 9 callers I have the EV of a bet at $197. Certainly higher, but unfortunately hands are not won after the flop is over. I understand my logic is a little irrational, but hopefully you see where I am coming from.

Comment: With that said, if we're talking about Jamming I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the equity values for each choice of 2 cards vs 8 other players with random holdings:

```
AA  34.57%
KK  29.21%
QQ  24.86%
AKs 22.65%
JJ  21.68%
AQs 21.18%
KQs 20.50%
AJs 19.89%
KJs 19.39%
AKo 19.20%
TT  19.14%
ATs 18.93%
QJs 18.85%
KTs 18.53%
QTs 18.17%
JTs 17.96%
AQo 17.47%
99  17.20%
A9s 16.90%
KQo 16.90%
K9s 16.26%
A8s 16.22%
AJo 16.10%
T9s 16.08%
Q9s 15.97%
J9s 15.87%
88  15.86%
KJo 15.69%
A5s 15.68%
A7s 15.63%
A4s 15.54%
QJo 15.30%
A3s 15.21%
A6s 15.15%
ATo 15.14%
K8s 14.94%
A2s 14.78%
77  14.76%
T8s 14.72%
KTo 14.67%
JTo 14.52%
98s 14.50%
Q8s 14.49%
J8s 14.45%
K7s 14.43%
QTo 14.36%
K6s 13.99%
66  13.94%
87s 13.86%
K5s 13.67%
97s 13.57%
K4s 13.37%
T7s 13.35%
55  13.29%
K3s 13.25%
Q7s 13.23%
76s 13.18%
J7s 13.16%
K2s 13.10%
Q6s 12.97%
44  12.93%
86s 12.91%
65s 12.81%
A9o 12.68%
33  12.60%
22  12.58%
54s 12.57%
Q5s 12.56%
T9o 12.53%
96s 12.47%
Q4s 12.39%
K9o 12.35%
75s 12.28%
J6s 12.21%
T6s 12.18%
J9o 12.17%
Q3s 12.07%
Q9o 12.06%
Q2s 12.01%
A8o 11.95%
64s 11.94%
J5s 11.92%
85s 11.78%
53s 11.64%
J4s 11.56%
A5o 11.46%
J3s 11.43%
A7o 11.32%
95s 11.27%
74s 11.26%
T5s 11.25%
J2s 11.20%
43s 11.15%
A4o 11.14%
T8o 11.05%
98o 10.94%
T4s 10.91%
A6o 10.88%
63s 10.86%
A3o 10.86%
T3s 10.84%
K8o 10.79%
84s 10.74%
J8o 10.69%
T2s 10.67%
52s 10.62%
Q8o 10.47%
94s 10.41%
42s 10.37%
A2o 10.35%
K7o 10.19%
73s 10.17%
87o 10.17%
93s 10.02%
92s 9.95%
32s 9.91%
62s 9.80%
97o 9.79%
83s 9.78%
K6o 9.78%
76o 9.63%
T7o 9.60%
82s 9.51%
K5o 9.43%
72s 9.26%
65o 9.21%
J7o 9.20%
Q7o 9.16%
86o 9.15%
K4o 9.10%
K3o 8.96%
54o 8.90%
Q6o 8.75%
75o 8.73%
K2o 8.66%
96o 8.61%
Q5o 8.39%
T6o 8.33%
64o 8.25%
Q4o 8.15%
J6o 8.09%
53o 8.02%
85o 8.01%
Q3o 7.92%
Q2o 7.70%
J5o 7.68%
43o 7.52%
74o 7.49%
J4o 7.47%
95o 7.38%
J3o 7.23%
T5o 7.23%
63o 7.19%
J2o 7.04%
T4o 6.94%
52o 6.89%
84o 6.87%
T3o 6.74%
42o 6.60%
T2o 6.53%
73o 6.42%
94o 6.37%
32o 6.15%
93o 6.13%
62o 6.04%
92o 5.93%
83o 5.84%
82o 5.61%
72o 5.41%
```

Answer (score 0):

AA has the most equity, but take into account that you are probably not going all-in. Speculative hands, particuarly those more likely to hit the nuts (say A5s) may not be much less profitable when playing 9-handed deep stacks into the flop

Comment: That's good point, but the case mentioned actually concerns when all 9 other players are also in the hand.

Comment: Sure, but it didn't say "all 9 players are all-in"

Comment: But they're all in-the-hand, also being all-in is a different matter.

Comment: They are all in the hand, that's why I want speculative hands with high nut-value rather than raw equity hands